# Adding function arguments to classes when subclassing

Tags: python, oop, subclassing

I've got a Person object:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

# create a Person object
a = Person('eric', 29)
```

And I want to extend the constructor to include country as well (which defaults to 'US'), without having to respond every time the prototype of `Person.__init__` changes.  I can obviously make this work:

```
class CountryPerson(Person):
    def __init__(self, country='US', *args, **kwargs):
        Person.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.country = country
```

The problem here is that I have no way of using the default value of 'US' while also passing in `name` and `age` as un-named arguments to the constructor.  Basically, I can create a US person the following ways:

```
CountryPerson('US', 'robert', 15)      # not taking advantage of the 'US' default
CountryPerson(name='robert', age=15)   # country defaults to 'US'
```

What I want to be able to do these types of things:

```
CountryPerson('robert', 15)
CountryPerson('robert', 15, 'JP')
```

Is there any way to do this in python?  I know that I could add something into `**kwargs` like this:

```
class SloppyCountryPerson(Person):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.country = kwargs.pop('country', 'US')
        Person.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

But now the function isn't really self-documenting any more (it's not even obvious that `country` is a valid argument to the function, much less that it's default value is 'US').

I guess the real problem is that python won't let me add `country` to the end of arguments after `**kwargs`, do this:

```
class GoodCountryPerson(Person):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, country='US'):
        Person.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.country = country
```

Any way around?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the function "isn't really self-documenting" because it's not obvious that `country` is a valid argument, when it's not a problem that it's not obvious that `name` and `age` are valid arguments? There's not much worse than a class like `GoodCountryPerson` mysteriously ceasing to work because a method *in some other class* changed.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 3 added keyword-only arguments, which I think are the generally recommended way of making extensible call signatures: `func(*, func_specific_arg=default, **kwargs)`

Comment: What is wrong with `SloppyCountryPerson`? It seems fine to me.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths you make a really valid point.  I guess it feels *slightly* different to me because just looking at the function prototype  + class definition is enough to "solve" for what is going on... but you're totally right it could easily break GoodCountryPerson.  I've often flirted with the idea of always using named-arguments no matter what, and this sounds like even more evidence of what a good idea that is.

Comment: @Blckknght I am not using python 3 but I will check that out, thanks!

Comment: If you want `CountryPerson.__init__` to be truly self-documenting, it surely must be `(self, name, age, country='US')`. I think the issue of dealing with changes to signatures in the base-classes is trivial. In practice, once you've got the overall design figured out, such changes will be quite rare.